# Send data to view from controller function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a little new to Angular, and I think I'm missing a key step in sending data from the controller to be able to display in my view.

The functionality I'm looking to create is that a user inputs search requirements into a form and clicks the submit button. Clicking the submit button fires a function in the controller (`getQuote()`), which makes an API call and returns the API response to  be displayed in the view the form redirects to. I've been able to have my function print the response to the console successfully, but the view remains blank.

Here is my code:

**Jade template for search form**

```
div(ng-controller="StockCtrl")
    form(action="/#/stock/quote")
        div(class="form-group")
            h3 Enter your stock symbol
            input(type="text" placeholder="AAPL ..." class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="formData.symbol")
            br
            h3 What time period are you interested in?
            input(type="date" id="startdate" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="formData.startdate")
            br
            button(type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="getQuote()") Compare
```

**Controller**

```
var stockrControllers = angular.module('stockrControllers', []);

stockrControllers.controller('StockCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
    function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

  $scope.stockData = [];
  $scope.formData = [];

  $scope.getQuote = function(startdate){
    var symbol = $scope.formData.symbol;
    var startdate = new Date($scope.formData.startdate);
    var startday = startdate.getDate();
    var startmonth = startdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var startyear = startdate.getFullYear();
    var enddate = new Date(startdate);
    enddate.setDate(startday + 5);
    var endday = enddate.getDate();
    var endmonth = enddate.getMonth() + 1;
    var endyear = enddate.getFullYear();

    //format dates to work with API call
    startdate = startyear + "-" + startmonth + "-" + startday;
    var enddate = endyear + "-" + endmonth + "-" + endday;

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/stock/' + symbol + '/' + startdate + '/' + enddate
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.stockData = response;
        console.log($scope.stockData);
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('Error:' + response);
    });

  };

}]);
```

**Jade template for view to print data**

```
h1 Stock Data

div(ng-controller="StockCtrl")
    div(ng-repeat="stock in stockData")
        p stock data: {{stock}}
```

When I don't have my API calls wrapped in a function, and instead just use an if statement (like `if($scope.formData){..}`), I can display the API response just fine in the view. However, putting the call in a function however is preventing the data from making it to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared two separate `div(ng-controller="StockCtrl")` and each one has it's own `$scope`.  If you merge them into a single div, then `$scope.stockData` will be visible:

```
div(ng-controller="StockCtrl")
    form(action="/#/stock/quote")
        div(class="form-group")
            h3 Enter your stock symbol
            input(type="text" placeholder="AAPL ..." class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="formData.symbol")
            br
            h3 What time period are you interested in?
            input(type="date" id="startdate" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="formData.startdate")
            br
            button(type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="getQuote()") Compare

    div(ng-repeat="stock in stockData")
        p stock data: {{stock}}
```

Comment: That totally fixed it! Thank you, I didn't realize I was declaring two different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

response.data contain actual contents. so try replacing your api call code as shown below

```
$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api/stock/' + symbol + '/' + startdate + '/' + enddate
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.stockData = response.data;
        console.log($scope.stockData);
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('Error:' + response);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Suresh Chahal for the suggestion. Using "response.data" instead of just "response" made the information in my console more targeted to what I need, but the data still isn't being printed on the page.